# Minimum volume size to enable versioning

Tags: macos, versions, disk-volume

I have certain documents stored on a password protected disk image stored on Dropbox. Since the documents are small text documents, I made the image small (100 MB). But now I'm getting the following message when I save a document:

> The document “foo.tex” is on a volume that is too small to support
>   permanent version storage.
>
> You will not be able to access older versions of this document once
>   you close it.

I have another 2 GB image which doesn't give rise to this warning.  So my question is, what's the minimum volume size I should use to avoid this warning?

Comment: I have this question too.  Nobody?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For others looking for an answer, it's 600 MB or larger (599 fails, 600 succeeds). Using a sparse disk helps save space from using a "too large" volume, FWIW.